# How to construct an object in 2 go-s to comply with an interface?

Tags: typescript

Say I have a following interface.

```
interface Person {
    age: number
    name: string
}
```

Now I want to construct an object that complies with the interface in two commands. How can I pull it off?

```
let boss = {age:50}
boss.name = "John"; // error
// now I want boss to be of type Person
```

Edit: I wish not to use optionals in this case, I want to keep the types strict.

Comment: You cannot construct an object in two goes like you are asking for. If a property is required, you have to set it. The best you could do is set one to null or undefined, then set it later.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan is that a shortfall of the language, or rather a feature?

Comment: A feature. The ability to make types have optional and required properties when building them using object literal is a powerful thing indeed.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it still kind of sucks, when you create an object with an optional in one place and you have to keep doing  typechecks throughout the whole app - since you used the optionals in the interface - even though you know, that where is this property. too bad there's no workaround for it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the interface with optional name:

```
interface Person {
    age: number
    name?: string
}
```

And use it:

```
let boss: Person = {age:50}
boss.name = "John";
```

Comment: is there a way without modifying the interface? I'd strongly prefer not to have anything optional just because I cannot construct the object in one command